# For two independent variables $X$ and $Y$, and $Z=XY$, what is the intuition behind why $Cov(X,Z) = Cov(X, XY) = E(Y)\cdot Var(X)$?

Tags: probability

Given two independent variables $X$ and $Y$, and $Z=XY$, it is easy to see that

$$
Cov(X,Z) = E(Y)\cdot Var(X)
$$

Is there an intuitive way to think about why we can decompose it so cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, it is easily shown that the covariance between $X$ and $XY$, when the two random variables are independent, shall be the product of the expectation for $Y$ and the variance for $X$.

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(X,XY)&=\mathsf E(X^2Y)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(XY)&&\text{by definition}\\&=\mathsf E(Y)\cdot\big(\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\big)&&\text{via independence}\\&=\mathsf E(Y)\cdot\mathsf{Var}(X)&&\text{by definition}\end{align}$

Intuitively, *because* of the independence, the joint variability of $X$ and $XY$, comes from $X$ in both, but from $Y$ in only one. Much the way $\mathsf{Cov}(X,aX)=a\mathsf{Var}(X)$.